# Can I use custom JSON format for incoming webhooks

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a JSON payload that is being sent to Slack using the URL provided by Slack when installing the Incoming Webhook app.
The JSON payload is not in the expected format by slack.

I would like to write an app (or find a way) that receives this JSON phrase it to the correct format and then displays it on the configured slack Channel.

See example below:
if i send the following JSON
`{"message":"Allow me to reintroduce myself!"}`.
This will not work. we need to change "message" to "text".

So my json payload is not within the needed format, however it is still a json.

How can i catch the json payload? and parse it ?
i would like to do this all on slack with no third party or "middle man" apps.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 4):

No.

Slack does not provide a custom format for incoming webhooks. You need to adhere to the official format.

There also is no way to intercept the message and transform it to the Slack format.

The only way to achieve this is to use a "middle man" app for the transform:

- Message is send to middle man app's URL
- Middle man app transforms to Slack format
- Middle man sends message to Slack

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe still helpful today: https://slack.dev/bolt-js/tutorial/getting-started#create-an-app and https://github.com/seratch/bolt-starter